# Single selection radioButton

Tags: ios, swift, radio-button

So I have 3 buttons

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    weeklyRadioButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "a"), for: .normal)
    weeklyRadioButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "b"), for: .selected)

    biWeeklyRadioButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "a"), for: .normal)
    biWeeklyRadioButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "b"), for: .selected)

    noThanksRadioButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "a"), for: .normal)
    noThanksRadioButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "b"), for: .selected)
}

@IBAction func biWeeklyRadioButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    weeklyRadioButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "a"), for: .normal) . 
    // its not changing then image of the button.
    noThanksRadioButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "a"), for: .normal)
}
```

and similar two Actions for other two buttons.

Current code allows multiple selection of button.
I want to know the way to implement to single selection in buttons.

so lets say i selected button 1
on selecting button 2, button 1 gets deselected

Comment: is this possible to add additional code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code. Please also make a note that all of the button outlets should be connected to the below action method.

```
@IBAction func anyRadioButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    //Reset all of them first
    weeklyRadioButton.isSelected = false
    biWeeklyRadioButton.isSelected = false
    noThanksRadioButton.isSelected = false

    //Highlight associate button
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
}
```

Comment: is not a valid answer related to the question

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, I've edited my post. Please check once and let me know am I missed something. Thank you...!!!